# Quick draft mode

Tags: draft

Writing a document with quite a few figures (50+) so when it complies, it can take 3-5 minutes. When I want to run it in draft mode, it reduces the compile time to about 5 seconds which is loads better so I'm doing it a lot. I'm using:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

for normal and draft mode respectively on texmaker. My question is: is there some kind of macro or command I can write so I can change between modes without having to navigate to line 163 in my document master and write or delete '[draft]' each time I switch? I'd love to be able to build either using 'f1' for build and 'ctrl+f1' for draft build for example.

I know it sounds lazy, but if it can be done, I'd like to.

Cheers.

Comment: `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`?

Comment: Your preamble is sufficiently long so that the loading of the `graphicx` package doesn't occur until line 163 of the master tex file?

Comment: Indeed. It's a Phd thesis for materials science so it's full of a ton of science-y packages, title pages, authors declaration crap bla bla.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to specify the `draft` option at the `\documentclass` level rather than at the level of individual packages. That way, the option will be passed to *all packages* that recognize it, further speeding up the compilation process. The `hyperref` package, for one, recognizes the option `draft` as well; if the option is specified, all hypertext options are turned off and no hyperlinking is performed.

Oh, the opposite of "`draft`" is "`final`".

Comment: Thanks Mico, that helps just for the sake of locating the relevant line.